# Linq transformation help needed

Tags: c#, json, linq

I've got a List of this object:

```
public class WebinarAttendeesList {
    public int wa_id { get; set; }
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string JoinTime { get; set; }
    public string TimeInSession { get; set; }
    public string LeaveTime { get; set; }
    public int FirstPollCount { get; set; }
    public int SecondPollCount { get; set; }
    public int AttendedWebinar { get; set; }
    public int Makeup { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string RegistrantKey { get; set; }
    public string webinarKey { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using this Linq code:

```
var webinars = new
{
    Webinars = r.GroupBy(x => new { x.PID, x.FullName }).
    Select(y => new
    {
        PID = y.Key.PID,
        FullName = y.Key.FullName,
        AffReceived = 0,
        Attendances = y.Select(z => new
        {
            WebinarKey = z.webinarKey,
            RegistrantKey = z.RegistrantKey,
            TimeInSession = z.TimeInSession,
            FirstPollCount = z.FirstPollCount,
            SecondPollCount = z.SecondPollCount,
            AttendedWebinar = z.AttendedWebinar
        })
    })
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webinars);
```

to transform the List to JSON. But, I think I'd rather 
have it transformed into a `List<FinalWebinarAttendeesList>` (see below 
definition). The JSON that it produces looks correct and passes lint.

When I try to do this:

```
List<FinalWebinarAttendeesList> fl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FinalWebinarAttendeesList>>(json);
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WebinarProject.Models.FinalWebinarAttendeesList]' 
because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or 
change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a 
primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) 
that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be 
added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 
'Webinars', line 1, position 12.
```

How can I either transform this directly into the object I want, or be able to deserialize it into the object I want?

**FinalWebinarAttendeesList definition:**

```
public class FinalWebinarAttendeesList
{
    public FinalWebinar Webinars {get; set; }
}
public class FinalWebinar
{
    public int PtID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int AffReceived  { get; set; }
    public List<FinalWebinarAttendee> Attendances { get; set; }

}
public class FinalWebinarAttendee
{
    public string RegistrantKey { get; set; }
    public string TimeInSession { get; set; }
    public int FirstPollCount { get; set; }
    public int SecondPollCount { get; set; }
    public int AttendedWebinar { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. is that code complete ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created only one `Webinar` instance, but you are trying to deserialize a list of `Webinar`s. Try:

```
FinalWebinarAttendeesList fl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FinalWebinarAttendeesList>(json);
```

Comment: `FinalWebinarAttendeesList fl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FinalWebinarAttendeesList>(json);` produces same error.

Comment: @MB34 Could you provide the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Changing the FinalWebinarAttendeesList Webinars member to a List<Webinars> worked. `public List<FinalWebinar> Webinars {get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

I created a json sample output using random data and and I found that you are trying to deserialize the json with the wrong object.
Json output:

```
{"Webinars":[{"PID":453,"FullName":"jdis","Attendances":[{"WebinarKey":"kdnsaod","RegistrantKey":"udhaso","TimeInSession":"hdija","FirstPollCount":45,"SecondPollCount":45,"AttendedWebinar":0}]}]}
```

The object has de following structure:

```
public class Attendance
{
    public string WebinarKey { get; set; }
    public string RegistrantKey { get; set; }
    public string TimeInSession { get; set; }
    public int FirstPollCount { get; set; }
    public int SecondPollCount { get; set; }
    public int AttendedWebinar { get; set; }
}

public class Webinar
{
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Webinar> Webinars { get; set; }
}
```

And for Deserializing the object:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```